# LINQ left join with nullable values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
from t in Tasks
join user in UserInfo on t.Publisher equals user.Account into temp
from userinfo in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    t.Title,
    IsCertificated = userinfo.IsCertificated
}
```

some code like up. IsCertificated is type of boolean, when userinfo is null, this query will not work.

> Not to assign a Null value type for the System.Boolean

I know it can modify:

```
 select new
    {
        t.Title,
        IsCertificated =userinfo == null?false: userinfo.IsCertificated
    }
```

But, **my userinfo has too many not null properties**.How can I dispose it ?

Comment: What exactly is the question, seems you have figured out how to fix your problem?

Comment: @Magnus thank you. My question is: my userinfo table has too many properties, I think  coding userinfo == null?XX: userinfo.XXX for every property is such a poor way. Is there some good method?

Comment: @yubaolee Create a 'model' class... so you would then use 'select new MyUserTaskModel()'... then in the properties set method you do the null check or indeed do it in the constructor etc.... object / class mapping is boring... or use something more automated such as AutoMapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the conditional operator out of the object creation.

```
from t in Tasks
join user in UserInfo on t.Publisher equals user.Account into temp
from userinfo in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select userinfo != null
    ? new
        {
            t.Title,
            IsCertificated = userinfo.IsCertificated
        }
    : new
        {
            t.Title,
            IsCertificated = false
        }
```